# Converting to and from Unicode in PHP

Tags: php, unicode

Hey, I'm using php 5 and need to communicate with another server that runs completely in unicode. I need to convert every string to unicode before sending it over. This seems like an easy task, but I haven't been able to find a way to do it yet. Is there a simple function that returns a unicode string? i.e. convert_to_unicode("the string i'm sending")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, iconv worked. The trouble is that this is a windows server, so I had to do it in little-endian. UTF-16LE works. Here's the working code:

```
iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-16LE", "data to send")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **[utf8_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)** and **[utf8_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php)** functions. Also, you may need to go through **[Multibyte String](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php)** to deal with specific encoding with those mb functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either :

- [`utf8_encode`](https://www.php.net/utf8_encode) / [`utf8_decode`](http://fr.php.net/utf8_decode)
- The [`mb_*` Multibyte String](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) functions ; in your case, see [`mb_convert_encoding`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)
- [iconv](https://www.php.net/iconv) and the [`iconv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [utf8_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)

Comment: I strongly doubt php.net will become outdated. This link is sufficient.